# getjson obj name and iterate child obj's

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, getjson

I'm fresh to js and web dev for that matter and am looking for some help.

I'm trying to grab enough information to format and make another request. This is what i have so far

JavaScript

```
$( document ).ready(function(sb_shows) {
    $.getJSON( "http://<myname>/api/<apikey>/?cmd=shows&callback=?", function(shows_obj) { 
        //$.each(shows_obj, function(key, value) { 
        if ( shows_obj.result == "success") {
            document.write(shows_obj.result);

            $.each(shows_obj.data, function(key, value) { 

                $.each(this.cache function(key, value) { 
                    document.write( "<p> "+value.banner+"<p>");
                });

                document.write( "<p>"+value.show_name+" - "+value.tvrage_id+ "<p>");

            });
        }
        else {
            document.write("fail..");
        }

    });
});
```

JSON Sample

```
{
"data": {
    "72023": {
        "air_by_date": 0, 
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1, 
            "poster": 1
        }, 
        "language": "en", 
        "network": "HBO", 
        "next_ep_airdate": "", 
        "paused": 0, 
        "quality": "SD", 
        "show_name": "Deadwood", 
        "status": "Ended", 
        "tvrage_id": 3267, 
        "tvrage_name": "Deadwood"
    }, 
    "72231": {
        "air_by_date": 1, 
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1, 
            "poster": 1
        }, 
        "language": "en", 
        "network": "HBO", 
        "next_ep_airdate": "2013-09-13", 
        "paused": 0, 
        "quality": "HD720p", 
        "show_name": "Real Time with Bill Maher", 
        "status": "Continuing", 
        "tvrage_id": 4950, 
        "tvrage_name": "Real Time With Bill Maher"
    }, 

}, 
"message": "", 
"result": "success"
}
```

What i'm hoping to achieve is grab the id under data (e.g. 72023 and 72231), I originally thought i'd be able to do something like

```
$(this).parent()
```

Its a object however and that doesn't appear to work

Also I'd like to be able to iterate through the sub obj's, something like below

```
$.each(shows_obj.data, function(key, value) { 
    $.each($(this).cache function(key, value) { 

        document.write( "<p> "+value.banner+"<p>");

    });
    document.write( "<p>"+value.show_name+" - "+value.cache.banner+ "<p>");
});
```

Any and all recomendations/suggestions will be appreciated. Please explain suggestions, i'm kinda slow:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `$.each()` call on the `data` object, your `key` is actually the ID number you'r e looking for. Google quickly gave me [an introduction to JSON](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/) which might help you out.

As per the [jQuery.each documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) the `this` keyword is the same as the `value` keyword. Your `$.each($(this).cache, ...)` should simply be `$.each(this.cache, ...)` or `$.each(value.cache, ...)` as you're not traversing the dom (`$(..)`) but passing an object to the `$.each()` function. Just like in the earlier case if you traverse `this.cache` you would have your callback be called twice:

```
// first
key => banner
value => 1

// second
key => poster
value => 1
```

If you would've just wanted the banner from the cache the thing to do would've been: `value.cache.banner` in your original `$.each(shows_obj.data, ...)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so how do i get the value of the key? from your first comment?  Also i have already tried $.each(this.cache, ...) no luck

Comment: Actually "document.write( "<p>"+key+" - "+value.show_name+" - "+value.tvrage_id+ "<p>");" did what i was looking for Thanks for your help

Comment: @jsonnewb `key` is a value itself ;-) So just assign it somewhere or pass it to a function for output. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the answer to your question : )